# A pedagogical semi-rigorous review of topological phases, topological order, and related subjects

Tags: resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

I'm looking for a pedagogical review or book about topological phases, topological order, TQFTs, and related subjects.

The ideal thing would be a mix of rigorous definitions and physical examples, with something giving me a physical idea of what's going on.

Right now the only things I can find are either a lot of category theory with no physics at all or a lot of handwaving about the Toric code (after having read about it in a bunch of different sources, I still don't understand what's "topological" about it, or how does it exemplify a more general concept of "topological order").

Does anybody know anything of the sort?

Comment: A potentially interesting book is the upcoming "Topological Phases of Matter" by R. Moessner and J.E. Moore. Posting it as a comment instead of an answer, because I haven't read it, and can't really comment on how well it fits your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

For topological band theory (single-particle picture) [the online course by TU Delft](https://topocondmat.org) could be a nice starting point. A more thorough approach on topological insulators can be found at the [lecture notes by Aboth](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295) or at the classic book *Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors* by A. Bernevig for instance.

On topological order, TQFTs and the toric code, S. Simon has a nice [protobook](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/topological2016/TopoBook.pdf) at his [website](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/).